# std::list question: iterator = list_name.begin() is crashing

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, stdlist

I have a class called PacketList. It has a private member that is a std::list:

**std::list<Packet_t> packets_;** (**Packet_t** is a struct that I defined globally)

and a private member that is an iterator over that list:

**std::list<Packet_t>::iterator it = packets_.begin();**

I have a public member function that returns an element of the list, one at a time:

```
Packet_t advance_one_packet() {
       if (it != packets_.end()) {
           it++;
       }
       else {
           it = packets_.begin();
       }
       Serial.print("current packet is ");
       Serial.println(it->name);
       return *it;
   }
```

**advance_one_packet()**
is called from main.cpp every few seconds, to display the contents of the next packet. It's not called if the list is empty.

This all works perfectly the first time through the list. But after it returns the last element in the list, and then does **it = packets_begin()** something bad happens. I know this because at that point, **Serial.print("current packet is ");** succeeds, but **Serial.println(it->name);** crashes HARD! My serial monitor output looks like this:

```
current packet is BME280temp
current packet is BME280pressure
// now it's trying to show the first element again:
current packet is $��?4␒��␐␀␀␀v���@␙�?␁�Al ␀␀␀xV����@␙�?␁�Al ␀␀␀xV�� (etc., etc.)
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? I should be able to keep looping through the list, right? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: It seems you might be printing content of `packets_.end()` if the function is called when `it + 1 == packets_.end()`. But without [mcve] we can't tell for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about the minimal reproducible example. I will try to do that. 

But @Yksisarvinen, I don't think it's trying to print the content of `packets_.end()`. If it IS at `packets_.end()`, the next line of code is to set `it = packets_.begin()`. Unless my logic is wrong?

Comment: You have the answer pretty much, but I'm not sure if it explains the logic issue. You increment *after* you check for `end()`, so you never know if `it` after increment is not equal to `end()`. You would check that in next function call, but that's too late, you already invoked UB. As some other comment said, you need to check for empty list, then increment, then check for end and reassign `it` to `begin()` if true.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that `end()` doesn't refer to the last element, but "one past" the last element.

```
[packet 0] -> [packet 1] -> [packet 2] -> [end indicator]
^^^^^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
packets_.begin()                          packets_.end()
```

When you enter the function with `it` pointing to the *last* element (packet 2), it does *not* equal `.end()`, so you increment the iterator. Now it *does* equal `.end()`, and your following call to `it->name` tries to dereference some unspecified location, which shows up as garbage in your output.

Comment: The fix: Handle the empty list case elsewhere and test for end AFTER the increment.

Comment: @samw - that was what I was missing! By sprinkling **std::distance(it.begin(), it)**, then sending the results to the serial monitor, I saw exactly what you are saying - I was trying to print an element AFTER the last element. Here's how it looks now, and it works perfectly:
`Packet_t advance_one_packet() {
       if (it == packets_.end()) {
           it = packets_.begin();
       }
       return *it++;
   }`
So simple, now that I understand it. Thanks so much!
(Sorry for the weird code display - I can't figure out how to make it look like it should.)